# how to make if within 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

How to write an error to the console when I have not received an answer within 30 seconds?

```
const req = await axios.post(`http://316.132.61.31:2000`)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I need to understand how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `timeout` option:

> `timeout` specifies the number of milliseconds before the request times out.
> If the request takes longer than `timeout`, the request will be aborted.
> timeout: 1000, // default is `0` (no timeout)

```js
const req = await axios.post(`http://316.132.61.31:2000`, null, { timeout: 30000 }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

See the official documentation [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

P.S. Please read the documentation before asking your next question about `axios` and indicate what you tried and what options you used in the question.